# Data table aggregation and using toString()

Tags: r, data.table

I was trying to create a function where I aggregate data table values on the basis of one column but I can't pass the argument in toString() for column names. The following example can show it better:

```
t1 <- data.table(P = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b"), Q = 
c("1","2","3","4","5","6"))

t1[ ,toString(Q), by = P] # this works
t1[ ,toString(colnames(t1)[2]), by = P] #  this does not give me the desired result
```

I get the following result with the above:

```
   P V1
1: a  Q
2: b  Q
3: c  Q
4: d  Q
```

As compared to the expected:

```
   P   V1
1: a 1, 5
2: b 2, 6
3: c    3
4: d    4
```

I have tried removing the quotes using noquotes() but nothing works out for me.
Can anyone point out where I might be making a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `get` to return the value

```
t1[ , toString(get(colnames(t1)[2])), by = P]
#   P   V1
#1: a 1, 5
#2: b 2, 6
#3: c    3
#4: d    4
```

Or with `eval/as.symbol`

```
t1[, toString(eval(as.symbol(names(t1)[2]))), by = P]
```

Or the standard way would be to specify in `.SDcols`

```
t1[, toString(.SD[[1]]), by = P, .SDcols = names(t1)[2]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!. What is the difference when I use noquote() though?

Comment: Also what if I have a string. I am planning to create a function that passes the column name as an argument.